# datetime argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 3 of convert function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to populate a table in my database with the following:

```
INSERT INTO student 
VALUES (102, 'Mr.', 'Fred', 'Crocitto', '101-09 120th St.', '11419', '718-555-5555', 
        'Albert Hildegard Co.', '22-JAN-03', 'BROSENZWEIG',
        CONVERT(DATETIME, '19-JAN-2007 00:00: 00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
        'BROSENZW', CONVERT(DATETIME, '22-JAN-2007 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

When I execute it, I get this error message:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 3 of convert function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with style `113` or just place string date literal:

> CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression **[ , style ]** )

```
CREATE TABLE #student(col DATETIME /*,rest_of_columns */);

INSERT INTO #student 
VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, '19-JAN-2007 00:00:00',113) /* ,rest_of_columns */);

INSERT INTO #student              -- style 113 is default so you can skip convert
VALUES ('19-JAN-2007 00:00:00');

SELECT *
FROM #student;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404485)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

Datetime accepts style.

> [@Brian Stork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4930405/brian-stork)
>
> When you convert TO datetime, you can't add a style. Datetime does not
>   accept style. You can convert datetime to character with a style, but
>   not the other way

According to official [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) documentation (section remarks):

```
╔══════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╗
║ Without century (yy) (1) ║ With century (yyyy) ║ Standard ║ Input/Output (3) ║
╚══════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╝
```

> <sup>3</sup> **Input when you convert to datetime;** output when you convert to character data.

Plus consider example like:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col DATETIME);

INSERT INTO #tab
VALUES ('12.02.02')
       ,(CONVERT(DATETIME, '12.02.02', 2));

SELECT *
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404618)**</kbd>

Result:

```
╔═════════════════════╗
║         col         ║
╠═════════════════════╣
║ 2002-12-02 00:00:00 ║
║ 2012-02-02 00:00:00 ║
╚═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: When you convert TO datetime, you can't add a style. Datetime does not accept style. You can convert datetime to character with a style, but not the other way.

Comment: @BrianStork Updated my answer

Comment: I had no idea. Thank you for showing me something new! I'll not make that mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0):

"What am I doing wrong?"  You are using Oracle/Postgres arguments for a SQL Server function (confusing `to_char()` with `convert()`).

The easiest solution is to use a string that represents the datetime using ISO standard formats:

```
INSERT INTO student 
    VALUES (102,'Mr.','Fred','Crocitto','101-09 120th St.','11419','718-555-5555',
            'Albert Hildegard Co.','22-JAN-03','BROSENZWEIG',
            '2007-01-19', 'BROSENZW', '2007-01-22');
```

Answer (score 0):

Datetime does not accept a style. If you want to convert it to a string, use the `convert(char(length),'datevale','style')` but if your column is type DATETIME, you don't need to add a style.

Don't use convert at all. Just use the string `'19-JAN-2007 00:00:00'`

Comment: `Datetime does not accept a style.`  This is not true